# cefsharp dropdowns in a TopMost container

Tags: winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm using cefsharp for Windows forms version 49.0.1 and I see that it has an  issue where drop down lists do not work if the window that wraps the component has its property `TopMost = true`.

Is there a workaround or something I can do to make the drop downs work (while keeping the TopMost property)?

Comment: This is a known issue with `Chromium` see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/657 In future I'd ask you do a little more research before asking a question.

Comment: I had seen that post, it is just that it dates back to 2014 (and last comment was in 2015) so I was wondering if any progress had been made in that regard, if not, then I'm asking if there is a workaround

Comment: Ideally you would have included that information, save me having to look it up!!! I'm not aware of any progress, `CEF` has deemed that it needs to be fixed in `Chromium`. I don't believe there is a workaround.